# How to allow an editor to edit all WordPress blog posts but have the last say as administrator?

Tags: plugins, posts, admin, user-roles

I run a simple WordPress setup hosted on SiteGround with no staging area and no special roles. The blog grew so much over the last few years that I barely write any content anymore.

I send a content brief and outline (Google Docs) for each article to the assigned writer, and they write the article on WordPress. I check, proof, edit, illustrate, and schedule or publish.

I am soon to hire an editor who will do all of the above. However, I feel weird giving so much power to somebody remote in a different country over my content. They could add malicious/paid-for links to existing content, and so on.

How can they "publish" every edit –even to published posts and pages– but not show the updated version publically, just yet. Changes would need to be reviewed manually by myself and confirmed, or rollbacked.

Any way of doing this? This is especially difficult for people editing currently published content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin and edit or add new user rule.

User Role Editor WordPress plugin allows you to change user roles and capabilities easy.
Just turn on check boxes of capabilities you wish to add to the selected role and click “Update” button to save your changes.

Comment: I think this plugin discussed here https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/how-to-edit-published-posts-in-wordpress-correctly/ may help